# How to get the natural width of the last box in a paragraph?

Tags: tex-core, paragraphs, plain-tex

I want to get the natural width of the last line in a paragraph. For example, the  last line of the following paragraph

> Georg Friedrich Bernhard Riemann (September 17, 1826 – July 20, 1866) was an influential German mathematician who made lasting contributions to analysis, number theory, and differential geometry, some of them enabling the later development of general relativity.

may be from `some` to `relativity`(that is, `some of them enabling the later development of general relativity.`) When the line-breaking happened, the last line will be put into an hbox, so, how can I get this hbox?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Georg Friedrich Bernhard Riemann (September 17, 1826 -- July 20, 1866) was an
influential German mathematician who made lasting contributions to analysis, number
theory, and differential geometry, some of them enabling the later development of
general relativity.
$$\mbox{the last line had length \the\predisplaysize}$$

\end{document}
```

Actually `\predisplaysize` is set to 2em more than the natural size so you may need to subtract 2em, depending..

---

To get the value without leaving a visible display math you can do something like this (copied from `afterpage`)

```
\makeatletter
Georg Friedrich Bernhard Riemann (September 17, 1826 -- July 20, 1866) was an influential German mathematician who made lasting contributions to analysis, number theory, and differential geometry, some of them enabling the later development of general relativity.
{\abovedisplayshortskip\z@\abovedisplayskip\z@
    \belowdisplayshortskip\z@\belowdisplayskip\z@
$$\global\dimen\@ne\predisplaysize
 \xdef\tmp{%
      \predisplaysize\the\predisplaysize
      \prevgraf\the\prevgraf\relax}%
$$\vskip\dimexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip\relax}\tmp

new para in which we can use \the\dimen\@ne


and another new para
```

Comment: I think `breqn` uses this approach: it only uses display math mode to grab info, and all of the actual setting is done in inline math mode.

Comment: yeah, wonderful! I like this simple and elegant method :-) But if I don't want the last line `$$\mbox ...` ... can you show me another way?

Comment: @JosephWright doesn't everyone? (`afterpage` also:-)

Comment: @TimLi look at afterpage and breqn etc you need a $$ ..$$ to set up `\predisplaysize` but then you can globally save that to another length register finish up the display math leaving no visible trace if you locally set abovedisplayskip and friends to zero

Comment: @TimLi code updated

Comment: And yet another non-math application that requires math mode.

Comment: It is the only way to solve this within standard TeX but even that only works if the paragraph is set such that the last line is at its natural width (e.g., \parfillskip not finite). Otherwise the returned value is \maxdimen :-)