# Starting a line where the previous line finishes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, verse, poetry

I have been using LaTeX for standard things like letters and scientific reports.
I recently came to visit my grandmother who writes some poetry and told her I could make a nice pdf from her handwritten verses -- which I start to regret :P...
I used the package verse and it is going all right, but in some specific poems, she wants a very 'exotic'  kind of positioning. She wants some **lines to start exactly where the former line finishes** like in this example:

[image: verse]

Do you know how I could, for instance, write a magic command `\magicom{}` that would generate the text above when used like:

```
This is some\\
\magicom{}text I would\\
like to\\
\magicom{}format\\
How can I do this with\\
\magicom{}LaTeX?
```

Comment: A quick fix, but not very elegant would be `\phantom`, like in: `This is some\\ \phantom{This is some}text I would\\ `

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Standard TeX has one way to measure the last line in a partial paragraph, it is a bit sneaky but there you go. At least it makes coding inside the document then nice and easy: normal line breaks with `\\` and special ones with `\magicom`. This allows even for some lines to be automatically broken.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\magicomadjust{0em}  % a way to adjust if the spacing should be different
\newdimen\indent@amount
\def\magicom{\relax
  \ifhmode $$%
    \predisplaypenalty\@M \postdisplaypenalty\@M
    \abovedisplayskip-\baselineskip \belowdisplayskip\z@
    \abovedisplayshortskip\abovedisplayskip
    \belowdisplayshortskip\belowdisplayskip
    \global\indent@amount\predisplaysize
     $$\count@\prevgraf \advance\count@-\thr@@
         \prevgraf\count@
    \global\advance\indent@amount-2em  % correction for \predisplaysize indent
    \global\advance\indent@amount\magicomadjust  % correction for verse env, for example
    \hspace*\indent@amount
  \else\typeout{*Not in hmode*}\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

%\begin{verse}
This is some\magicom
text I would\\
like to\magicom
format and it nicely allows for several lines  written with automatic lines breaks as well, as we can see here.
How can I do this with\magicom
\LaTeX?
%\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

This then gives us:

[image]

If we uncomment the `verse` environment above and use

```
\renewcommand\magicomadjust{-4em}
```

we get the following:

[image]

#### What does the code do?

- test if we are in horizontal mode (if not warning)
- start a display math formula (indeed :-)
- set various variables for math displays, so that this display doesn't really show up and mess up spacing (vertial skip is a negative baseline above and zero below, penalties are set so this isn't introducing a break, ...)
- then we store the `\predisplaysize` away (that is the width of the last line before the display + 2em) ... everything else was just done to get this variable set, i.e., doing the measurement for us
- then we end the display (and it takes up one line (empty) and because of the settings above this is not visible
- after the display we have to reduce the value of `\prevgraf` by 3 as a display takes up 3 lines (nominally in TeX's counting). This can be needed in some case when a `\parshape` is in effect
- then we reduce the saved value by 2em and and we add `\magicomadjust` (which I used for the `verse` example
- and finally we use the resulting value to produce the desired indentation after the display

Comment: @azetina there is another example (with not much more explanation:-) here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107726/how-to-get-the-natural-width-of-the-last-box-in-a-paragraph/107727#107727

Comment: Thank you, I do not quite undertand how the code works, but it works... I had to tweak the `\global\advance\indent@amount-2em` to `7em` for some reason... In any case, it makes minimalist an easy to read code which I like a lot.

Comment: @QuentinGeissmann probably because you are in some verse env or similar. see my updated code version that ehlps you with that

Comment: Your answer completely solves my problem. Is simple tu use and, as you wrote, supports line breaking. Also, thank you for spending some time to explain it. For these reasons, I accept it over the other answers which were also also great:).

Answer (score 38):

The `tabbing` environment provides this functionality where you designate the tabs via `\=` and skip to them using `\>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
This is some \= text I would \\
\> text I would \\
like to \= format \\
\> format \\
How can I do this with \= \LaTeX? \\
\> \LaTeX?
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

For completeness, I've doubled the content so you can see the tabbing is at the appropriate horizontal location. More [help on the use of `tabbing` is available from TeX Blog](http://texblog.net/help/latex/tabbing.html).

Answer (score 28):

I think it's simpler (and takes less markup) if you think of it as lowering the rest of the current line rather than making the next line start where the last one ended.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
{\obeylines%
\gdef\drop#1
{\smash{\lower\baselineskip\hbox{#1}}\par\vskip\baselineskip}}%
\begin{document}

\obeylines
This is some \drop text I would 
like to \drop format
How can I do this with \drop \LaTeX?

\end{document}
```

Comment: nice but this doesn't support multi-line verses where TeX does its own breaking if no \\ is given (as in the verse environment)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I know:-) But it's hard to believe you want control over the final words but can let TeX break other lines automatically. And anyway needed a technique different from the ones posted so far:-)

Comment: I can agree on the last part of the comment, but for allowing for auto breaks that is quite useful the way verse does it (using extra indent)

Answer (score 24):

And, of course, there's a solution using `\tikzmark`. Use `\Contline` at the end of a line where the effect mut be applied; for example, your text can be produced simply with

```
\noindent This is some\Contline
text I would\\
like to\Contline
format\\
This is one way to do it with\Contline
\LaTeX.
```

The code needs two runs to stabilize:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\tikzmark{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \coordinate (a);}
\newcommand\Advline{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\path let \p1 = (current page text area.west), \p2=(a) in node[anchor=west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text width={\x2}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand\Contline{\tikzmark\\\Advline}

\begin{document}

\noindent This is some\Contline
text I would\\
like to\Contline
format\\
This is one way to do it with\Contline
\LaTeX.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like @FrankMittelbach 's answer, it is nice and easy to use. It seems however more robust to the alteration of the length parameter of the verse environment `\begin{verse}[XX]`.

Comment: @QuentinGeissmann yes, you can use this solution inside virtually any construct and it will always produce the desired result.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: a very nice use of the `tikzmark` here :)

Answer (score 17):

For example (you can comment the line beginning with `\leavevmode`). Let us observe, that no duplication of text is needed, as in some other solutions.

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}


\def\magiccom#1{{#1}\\ \leavevmode\phantom{#1}}

\begin{verse}
Do you know how I could, for instance, write a magic command\\
\leavevmode\phantom{Do you know how I could,} for instance, write a magic command\\
\magiccom{Do you know how I could,} for instance, write a magic command

\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice and simple solution; the only catch is that you have to know where your line starts, i.e., the \phantom has to follow a \\. If that is not known the solution breaks.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps using the `verbatim` environment?

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
This is some text I would 
             text I would 
like to format 
        format 
How can I do this with \= \LaTeX? 
\LaTeX?
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\obeyspaces` will be better than a full scale shift to verbatim environment.

Comment: @Aditya yes I agree- I wasn't really expecting this answer to be taken too seriously.... I'm glad it's at the bottom!

Answer (score 5):

Another simple way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,parskip}
\newcommand\magic[1]{\parbox[t]{\widthof{#1}}{\leavevmode\\#1}\par}
\begin{document}

    This is some text \magic{I would}
    like to \magic{format} 
    How \magic{can \magic{I do \magic{this with \magic\LaTeX}}} 

\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]

Answer (score 3):

With the `tabto` package.  You may want to group-limit the scope of the `\\` redefinition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\newcommand\magicom{\tabto{\TabPrevPos}}
\let\svlf\\
\renewcommand\\{\tabto*{0pt}\svlf}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
This is some\\
\magicom{}text I would\\
like to\\
\magicom{}format\\
How can I do this with\\
\magicom{}LaTeX?
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one didn't have to worry about double line breaks, `\\\\` or if one wanted to collapse multiple adjacent line breaks into a single line break, then this is even easier.  The following definitions produce the same result as above because there are no multiple line breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\newcommand\magicom{\tabto{\TabPrevPos}}
\renewcommand\\{\tabto{0pt}}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
This is some\\
\magicom{}text I would\\
like to\\
\magicom{}format\\
How can I do this with\\
\magicom{}LaTeX?
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\versephantom` command in `poemscol` does exactly what you require. For your purposes you probably don't have to use all of `poemscol`. You can just take the `\versephantom` command from it, which is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\versephantom}[1]{\leavevmode\phantom{#1}}
```

The sextet of Yeats’s sonnet "Leda and the Swan," has such a broken line:

```
A shudder in the loins engenders there
The broken wall, the burning roof and tower
And Agamemnon dead.
                   Being so caught up,
So mastered by the brute blood of the air,
Did she put on his knowledge with his power
Before the indifferent beak could let her drop?
```

To set the broken line properly, issue:

```
And Agamemnon dead.\\
\versephantom{And Agamemnon dead.} Being so caught up,\\
```