# How to compose poetry with LaTeX

Tags: packages, templates

Well I have a very long poem (IX parts in 630 lines) and I want to format it with LaTeX. I know there is an environment called verse for this kind of task. But this is not a short verse, it a whole poem.

I saw in the CTAN few packages for this, but I'm not sure which would be the best choice. I only need to compose it well, in one language (Spanish), and that's all.

Does anyone knows what to use?

Comment: I think you refer to [CTAN: Topic verse](http://www.ctan.org/topic/verse). I cannot tell anything about strengths and weaknesses, but perhaps it is also just a matter of taste which one you want to use. Read manuals, test the packages with an excerpt of your looooooooong poem.

Comment: See also package `dramatist` and perhaps `poemscol`.

Comment: The following topic: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110314/starting-a-line-where-the-previous-line-finishes/110317#110317 might be also interesting for you.

Comment: there are packages with more complete solutions if you need that but I'll' note that `verse` is not intended for single verses but for poems, with each paragraph (ie separated by blank line) being a verse and line breaking being marked with `\\ ` so perhaps that is all you need.

Comment: I was reviewing the documentation of both packages: `dramatist`and `poemscol` and both look interesting, only that the documentation of `poemscol` I find it somewhat confusing, I have to read it again to better understand how to use this package. I feel that because the extension of the poem the verse environment just as you suggest falls short, that's why I asked about specialized packages, thanks.

Comment: @Aradnix: I did yesterday a quick look on package documentations, and `gmverse` looked also interesting …

Comment: Hi, are there news here? Can you write up an answer with an example of what you used in the end? Or even compare a few of those packages? Would be nice. And we get this off the unanswered list. Don't forget to ping me, so i can upvote. ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Nowadays I'm pretty busy writing my thesis to finish it, which is why I almost did not participate in the site. But let me finish with this and I'll write the answer you asked me.

Comment: Take your time and good luck :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, answering to the request of Johannes_B to answer this question, I explain how I solved this in the end.

The first thing I did (after ask here) was look for packages available in the CTAN to work with poetry. Among them I reached [`poemscol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/poemscol) which is the package I found and was consistent with what I needed.

However even after reading the documentation of the package had some doubts about how to use it. The main thing is that usually I work with `KOMA Script` instead the standard classes. So I got in touch with [John Burt](https://ctan.org/author/burt), the package author, who kindly responded to each and every one of my questions and even was kind enough to send me the `.tex` file from his first book of poetry which was a great gift and helped me much to dispel my doubts.

Since that did not require creating a critical edition, my doubts were relatively easy to solve.

Well, a kind of MWE, if it is useful for someone else, it would be something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,twoside,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[<language>]{babel}
%\usepackage[>option>]{csquotes} %If you regularly use it.
\usepackage{fancyhdr,makeidx,multicol}
\usepackage{keyval,ifthen,mparhack,lineno,poemscol} %The packages you need
\usepackage[letter,pdftex,cam,center]{crop}
\stanzaatbottom{*}
\nostanzaatbottom{\relax}
\raggedbottom
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000    
\renewcommand{\verseindent}{\hspace{-2em}}
\newtoks{\poemheader}
\newcommand{\humongousfont}{\fontsize{36}{40}\selectfont}
\global\verselinenumbersfalse
\setprosemodulo{70}
\nolinenumbers %Since it was not a critical edition    
\begin{document}
\begin{volumetitlepage} 
\begin{center}
{\Large Title}
\end{center}    
\end{volumetitlepage}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{2in}

\volumededication{To my Muse}
\end{volumetitlepage}

\begin{volumetitlepage}

\newpage

\poemtitle{Title of the book or poem}

\begin{poem}

\poemsectiontitle{I}

\begin{stanza}
\verseindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \versline
consectetur adipisicing elit, \verseline
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt \verseline
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\end{stanza}

\being{stanza}
Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris \verseline
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \verseline
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit \verseline
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore \verseline
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
\end{stanza}

\end{poem}
\end{document}
```

The `poemscol` package need to load the `lineno` package also and as you can see, the poem is an environment where each strophe or stanza is also an environment within you need to use `\verseline` command for break all the lines but the last one. You can add a `\verseindent` if you need it and much more.

Comment: poemscol only needs the lineno package if you are giving line numbers to prose sections. It does not need lineno if you are only giving line numbers to verse lines.