What is the best way to typeset shared lines with the dramatis package?
I am Looking for a way to typeset lines that are shared between actors using the dramatist package in verse mode.
Here is an example:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{dramatist}
\begin{document}
\Character[Person A]{Person A}{persona}
\Character[Person B]{Person B}{personb}
\DramPer

\begin{drama*}

\act

\scene

\StageDir{The stage directions.}

\personaspeaks
Starting the line, \\

\personbspeaks
finishing the line \\

\end{drama*}

\end{document}

My goal is to have the line for Person B start where the line for Person A ends.
There was a very similar question for poems in general that was already asked here: Starting a line where the previous line finishes.
Unfortunately, the solutions that were proposed there do not apply in this case. The poems, for which the solutions were proposed, always reference the previous line. However, in the case of a stage play, there is a change of actor in between, where the actor name is the previous line, not the one previously spoken by the other actor.
Also, having shared lines in a stage play is very common, so I would expect there to be a simple solution for this that I am overseeing in the documentation of the dramatist package (https://mirror.init7.net/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/dramatist/dramatist.pdf).
I would expect there to be a solution as simple as the solution proposing the tabbing package (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110323/172299). However, it seems that the tabbing environment, provided by the tabbing package, is not compatible with the drama* environment, provided by the dramatist package, resulting in compilation errors and messing up other alignments.
What would be the best way to achieve shared lines using the dramatist package?

You can use zref-savepos to store the horizontal position at the end of the line (in sp units) and insert a space at the beginning of the next line that is the size of the stored horizontal position minus the margin. This needs two runs because the positions are stored in the .aux file and read during the next run.
For storing positions zref-savepos needs a label. You can introduce a counter to ensure each saved position gets a unique label.
The margins are the default margin of 1inch + the variable \oddsidemargin + 1.5em for the verse environment + 1em extra because it didn't line up nicely (i.e., there must be an additional margin somewhere but I'm not sure where that comes from, so I added it manually).
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\newcounter{saveline}
\setcounter{saveline}{0}
\def\linesave{\stepcounter{saveline}\zsaveposx{line\thesaveline}}
\def\linecont{\hspace{\the\dimexpr\zposx{line\thesaveline}sp-1in-\oddsidemargin-2.5em\relax}}

\begin{document}
\Character[Person A]{Person A}{persona}
\Character[Person B]{Person B}{personb}
\DramPer

\begin{drama*}

\act

\scene

\StageDir{The stage directions.}

\personaspeaks
Starting the line,\linesave \\

\personbspeaks
\linecont finishing the line \\

\personaspeaks
This line is spoken by Person A on their own\\

\personbspeaks
But Person A knows\linesave \\

\personaspeaks
\linecont what comes next\\

\end{drama*}

\end{document}

This code leads to the following two lines in the .aux file:
\zref@newlabel{line1}{\posx{11054157}}
\zref@newlabel{line2}{\posx{12178425}}

Result after the second compilation:


Works like a charm, thank you very much for the quick solution! I actually considered zref but quickly abandoned it because I could not fathom what it would take to make it work :-)
