# Getting the length of the last line of paragraph w/o producing vertical space

Tags: formatting

Can I use $$\predisplaysize$$ to record the length of the last line of a paragraph without producing any output (vertical space)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newdimen\lastline

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[1]
$$\global\lastline=\predisplaysize$$

\lipsum[2]

The last line of the third paragraph was \the\lastline\ long
(minus 2em).  But how can
I record it without creating a gap between the 3rd and the 4th?
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should  not use `$$...$$` at all. That's deprecated syntax

Comment: @ChristianHupfer not sure that applies here, it is not being used to set any math at all, it's just that the facility is only available in display math mode because TeX is TeX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I know that this is a question about the length, but this should be possible with `\[...\]` as well then?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer no:-) (well it is harder in that case)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, that records a different length.

Comment: You just need to set the displaymath spacing parameters to zero locally, see Frank's answer in the suggested duplicate.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it's like commenting on the standard trick of `\romannumeral-\`\Q` to force expansion that the latex syntax to getting roman numerals is `\roman{..}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, for some reason the other answer doesn't work within reledpar paragraphs.  I'll accept that this is a duplicate and post a new question with a less minimal example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, turns out the answer that works in my case is yours: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107726/how-to-get-the-natural-width-of-the-last-box-in-a-paragraph/107727#107727

Comment: @Lawrence it happens sometimes that my code works:-)