# \setindent hack and alignment between parallel paragraphs with reledmac

Tags: formatting, reledmac, reledpar

Based on David Carlisle's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107726/how-to-get-the-natural-width-of-the-last-box-in-a-paragraph/107727#107727), I've defined a macro that stores the length of the last line of the current paragraph.  But when using it with reledmac and -par, it messes up the alignment parallel paragraphs. Does anyone understand why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\setindent{%
    {\abovedisplayshortskip\z@\abovedisplayskip\z@
    \belowdisplayshortskip\z@\belowdisplayskip\z@
$$\global\dimen\@ne\predisplaysize
 \xdef\tmp{%
      \predisplaysize\the\predisplaysize
      \prevgraf\the\prevgraf\relax}%
$$\vskip\dimexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip\relax}\tmp
}
\dimen\@ne=\parindent

\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum*[1]
\pend

\pstart
\lipsum*[2]
\pend

\pstart
\lipsum*[3]
\pend

\pstart
\lipsum*[4]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum*[5]\setindent
\pend

\pstart
\lipsum*[6]\setindent 
\pend

\pstart
\makeatletter
\noindent\hskip\dimen\@ne
\lipsum*[7]\setindent  
\pend

\pstart
\makeatletter
\noindent\hskip\dimen\@ne
\lipsum*[8]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure what problem you see, you set the indent three times but don't use the first one, the two that you do use seem to work OK, see places marked with `!!!!` [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MI5ga.png)

Comment: sorry, but what is the need ? what setindent should do ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the problem is that the paragraphs are not aligned/synced with the corresponding pars on page 2, which they are if the 3 `\setindent` are commented out.

Comment: @Maïeul, allow the next paragraph to begin where the previous ended (horizontally).

Comment: @Lawrence ok. strange need, but why not. The problem is that pstart / pend structure of reledmac/reledpar Does not contain any \vskip. It brokes all the way reledmac works.

Comment: @Maïeul, do you mean that it cannot be done? (it is a bit strange, but makes sense in context.)

Comment: I think it could be done, with an other method. I am looking on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36526/discussion-between-maieul-and-lawrence).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if you have time, could you look on the problem I mention in my solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why your solution bugs

\pstart…\pend must contain only normal text. Not mathematical display, and not \vskip. Any entry like this perturbate the way reledmac/reledpar split lines, and so the alignment.

## Principle of my solution

We will use a \setindent but OUTSIDE of the \pstart…\pend. To do that, we use the fact that in parallel typesetting, reledpar stores the \pstart…\pend content in numbered vbox. So we will copy the content of the box, and using some TeX' hacks on box mechanism, get the last line of the vbox. And then, using new code provide by David Carlisle, get the natural width of the lastline.

## Other inhancement

As explained by chat, you should not use `\maketaletter` without a corresponding `\makeatother`. And if you use many time command with @ in the name, you should wrap it in an other command. I have created a `\myindent` command.

## So, final code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% My new setindent
\def\setindent{%
\ifledRcol
  \setbox0=\expandafter\copy\csname l@dRcolrawbox\the\l@dnumpstartsR\endcsname%On rightside, copy the content of last \pstart…\pend pair
\else
  \setbox0=\expandafter\copy\csname l@dLcolrawbox\the\l@dnumpstartsL\endcsname%On leftside, copy the content of last \pstart…\pend pair
\fi
\expandafter\newdimen\csname l@\the\l@dnumpstartsR\endcsname%
\setbox0=\vbox{%
  \parindent=0pt%
  \setbox1=\vsplit0 to\baselineskip%Get only the last line in vbox0
  \unvbox0%Unvbox it
  \setbox0=\lastbox%Get the last line on the form of hbox
  \setbox0=\hbox{\unhbox0\unpenalty\unskip\unskip}
  \global\dimen\@ne=\wd0%
  }%We do it in a setbox in order to print nothing
}
% Avoid to use command with @ in the main text
\newcommand{\myindent}{\noindent\hskip\dimen\@ne}% I don't understand why we need such correction of 20pt !!! But it is not linked to reledmac,  as a test of your \setindent outside of any reledmac context can prove 
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum*[1]
\pend

\pstart
\lipsum*[2]
\pend

\pstart
\lipsum*[3]
\pend

\pstart
\lipsum*[4]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? 
\pend
\setindent
\pstart
\myindent\lipsum*[6]%
\pend
\setindent 
\pstart
\myindent
\lipsum*[7]%
\pend
\setindent  
\pstart
\myindent\lipsum*[8]
\pend
\setindent  
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages


\end{document}
```

## A variant

Maybe instead of

```
\newcommand{\myindent}{\noindent\hskip\dimen\@ne}
```

Do

```
\newcommand{\myindent}{\noindent\ \hskip\dimen\@ne}
```

It will add a space, as required after a final dot.

Comment: the 20pt is 2em (in the font current at the end of the para) `\predisplaysize` is 2em larger than the last line of the para, which is not the most obvious definition that you might imagine but that's the way it is, however if I understand your code correctly you don't need to use  `\predisplaysize` at all, you have the last line of the para in a box so you can just measure it  (taking in to account `\parfillskip`).

Comment: I have the last line in a box, indeed, but including the \parfillskip. So it width is everytime equals to \hsize.

Comment: just an other question : this 2em is fixed, or defined in a TeX length?

Comment: fixed in tex-the-program

Comment: yes but you can measure the box without the final skip by `\setbox2=\hbox{\unhcopy0\unpenalty\unskip\unskip}%or whatever unskips are needed` and then measure resulting box.

Comment: oh ! thanks. I didn't think to that. I have tried with `setbox2=\hbox{\unhcopy0}` and it works. Which skip / penalty the `\unpenalty\unskip\unskip` suppose to delete ?

Comment: if you just unhcopy then you get the natural size of the box so in the normal case where parfillskip is \fill that will shrink to 0 and you will get what you want but if \parfillskip is say 15pt plus 1fill to ensure the last line is never full, then if you just unbox then you will be 15pt too long, so you could either remove \parfillskip with \unskip or simply subtract the natural width of \parfillskip (which is probably easier)

Comment: @Lawrence : I have update the code using the comment of David. It is smarter ;-)